# SWI-Prolog, first delete an element then reverse the resulting list

Tags: list, prolog

I currently have my head wrapped around this issue - its driving me crazy. I'm new to Prolog, so I'm still understanding the very basics. From the title, all I'm trying to do is delete an element from a list, and then from that resulting list, reverse it.

So far, I done a bit of research in how do these functions separately on different lists, but I don't know exactly how to perform both of them (delete then reverse) on a single list..

My reverse and delete are below:

```
reverse(List, RevList) :-
    reverselist(List, [], RevList).
reverselist([], RevList, RevList).
reverselist([E|Elements], Accu, RevList) :-
    reverselist(Elements, [E|Accu], RevList).

del(Element, [Element|Tail], Tail).
del(Element, [Y|Tail], [Y|Tail1]) :-
    del(Element, Tail, Tail1).
```

And my attempt:

```
delete_reverse(Element, [Element|Tail], Tail1) :-
    // no idea what im doing below..
    del(Element, Tail, Tail1),
    reverse(Tail1, Tail).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `del` is missing a base case:

```
del(_,[],[]).
```

Then, your `delete_reverse` is almost right: you should use a different variable name to unify the results of `del` and the input of `reverse`:

```
delete_reverse(Element, [Element|Tail], Tail1) :-
    del(Element, Tail, Temp),
    reverse_family(Temp, Tail1).
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I get a singleton error with Tail1. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1280446 Ah, it should be `Tail1`, not `Tail` in the call of `reverse`.

Comment: Thanks, but its not 100% working correctly. For example delete_reverse('a', ['a','b','c'], List). will return List = ['c','b'] - thats fine. The problem is when 'a' is not the first element in the list. So delete_reverse('a', ['b','a','c'], List). will return false.